# How to add a key/value pair into nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
abcd = {
"ab": {
    "a": {
        "country": "",
        "url": ""
    },
    "b": {
        "country": "",
        "url": ""
    }
},
"cd": {
    "c": {
        "country": "",
        "url": ""
    },
    "d": {
        "country": "",
        "url": ""
    }
}
```

}

I need to add a `new_key` into each nested dictionary (right after `url` subkey).

I've tried to make a `for` loop by unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: please show us what you have tried. your `unsuccessful for loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i in abcd:
    for j in abcd[i]:
        abcd[i][j]['new_key'] = 'new_vale'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```py
for key, _value in abcd.items():
    for _key, value in _value.items():
        abcd[key][_key]["new_key"] = 'new_value'
```